# Merge multiple xml files to one file using glob

Tags: php, foreach, glob

I have three similar built xml files (the number og files will change over time) in the same directory. I would like to make an array of all the xml files in the directory of eny given time and use the glob function for this purpose - and that I can do. Then I would like to loop through this new merged xml file - but using the code below only get hold of the latter of the files. I don't know whats wrong:

```
$pastscores = glob('xml/score/*xml');
foreach($pastscores as $output) {
  $pastscore = file_get_contents($output);
}
```

The looks of my xml files as example beneath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <SECTION>
    <SEASONNO>7</SEASONNO>
  </SECTION>
</ROOT>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <SECTION>
    <SEASONNO>6</SEASONNO>
  </SECTION>
</ROOT>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <SECTION>
    <SEASONNO>5</SEASONNO>
  </SECTION>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: $pastscore .= file_get_contents($output); http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Please share your expected output and also share your code which you have tried.

Comment: @mr.void Concatenation will append `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` three times.

Comment: sure, for this case he could check the index in the foreach an substr if index > 0

Comment: The tiny dot before the = did the trick.

About the substr if index > 0. How to do that because I can't loop through the merged xml file as it is now?

Comment: My expected/hoped output would be:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <SECTION>
    <SEASONNO>5</SEASONNO>
    <SEASONNO>6</SEASONNO>
    <SEASONNO>7</SEASONNO>
  </SECTION>
</ROOT>

In a way so I can make a foreach loop on the the data...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way. I did the following

```
foreach($files as $file) {
  $pastscores = file_get_contents($file);
  $pastscore = new SimpleXMLElement($pastscores);
  foreach ($pastscore->children() as $output) {
    echo '<div class="box3 mix mix'.$output->SEASONNO.'">';
      echo '<p>'.$output->SEASONNO.'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Thank you for all your help.  :o)